# How to display the records before 1 minute time using linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

In my table entering records with current datetime.i need to display it continuously what are the records are entering in db.
for that writing a webservice in that every 1minute i need to display the new entered records .
How to write linq to sql query to display before 1minute entered records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save data in your database immediately but when you want to display data in Gridview you can make a delay with `Thread.Sleep(60000);`